# phpMyAdmin PHP Files Do Not Execute They Rather Get Opened in the Browser

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

The title describes the question.

I have PHP installed, Apache, MySQL and also phpMyAdmin in the htdocs folder of Apache. I installed them separately and do not use a compilation package. I did try to create a php file with phpinfo, which works and showcases that PHP is installed properly, though when I access:

localhost/phpmyadmin/setup/index.php

The file becomes opened in the browser and does not get executed, which means I am seeing the source code - though the same does not happen with phpinfo php file.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that php short tags are enabled in the php.ini.
If that senario stands, restart apache and you will be ok.

Comment: Why is there a need to enable short tags? phpMyAdmin is not even using short tags by my knowledge.

Comment: It's just a guess. From my experience I can tell that when you can see the source code of a .php file, in most cases short_open_tag is off.
Maybe an included file uses short tags.
You can try and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried it and it indeed worked, your assumption must be right, that phpMyAdmin is probably including a file with short codes, I would not have expected it. Thank you a lot.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. Please check the helpful answers as accepted so that others will be more willing to help you. ;)